# How to filter out certain objects in a table with certain ids? (Rails 4, Postgresql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

before I ask my question, I will provide some context.

I have 3 Models which interact with each other.

```
Scoreboard has many Teams. Team belongs to Scoreboard.
```

The following use a `through` table.

```
Scoreboard many-to-many with User.(let's call this Scoreboard.followers)

Team many-to-many with User.(Let's call this Team.members)
```

I have a Team_Members Controllers with the following method:

**Team_member#new Method:**

```
def new 
        @selected = true
        @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
        @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
        @team_members = @team.members
        @followers = @scoreboard.followers.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
end
```

What I'm attempting to do is display all the `Scoreboard followers` in my new.html.erb view. I can search through them and add members to a `Team` that is associated to the same `Scoreboard.`

Here's is the **new.html.erb** view:

```
<%= form_tag(new_scoreboard_team_team_member_path, :method => "get", id: "member-search-form", autocomplete: "off") do %>
<div class="row new-member-field">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Filter Members by Name", class:"form-control" %>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>

<% if @followers.any? %>  

        <% @followers.each do |follower| %>
            <div class="row member-follower-div" id="follower_<%=follower.id%>">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5 member-prof-link">
                    <%= link_to follower.name, user_path(follower.id) %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 member-add">
                    <%= link_to (add_scoreboard_team_team_member_path(@scoreboard,@team, follower)), method: :post, remote: true, :data => {:disable_with => ".."} do %>
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% end %> 

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 new-member-pages">
                <%= will_paginate @followers %>
            </div>
        </div>

<% end %>
```

Okay now for the question. The problem arises in the controller method. The @team.members and @scoreboard.followers both source objects from the Users table. **How would I filter out the User objects from the @scoreboard.followers that exist in the @team.members?** I don't want to display @followers on my view that are a part of the @team.members collection. **Also, as a bonus, I would like to alphabetically order the followers by user.name.**

I tried the `.where("users.id NOT IN (?)", @team_members.pluck(:id))` but if @team_members collection is null, no results are displayed on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like so:

```
def new 
        @selected = true
        @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
        @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
        @team_members = @team.members
        if (@team_members.any?)
           @wonderful_humans = @scoreboard.favourited_by.where("users.id NOT IN (?)", @team_members.pluck(:id)).search(params[:search]).sort_by{ |a| a.name.downcase }
        else
           @wonderful_humans = @scoreboard.favourited_by.search(params[:search]).sort_by{ |a| a.name.downcase }
        end
        @followers = @wonderful_humans.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
    end
```